# Website on window

Tags: macos, web, window

I want make simple mac app - window (1000x600px) with webkit.framework who go to web address when I open app. I make new project, add webkit control and I dont know where write website address. Help me please :-/

Answer (score 0):

A similar question and answer below on this website may help you:-

stackoverflow.com / questions /2255624 / how-to-use-process-start-or-equivalent-with-mono-on-a-mac-and-pass-in-argument

In C# or VB.NET (equal attention) something like

C#
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "firefox.exe",url);

VB.NET
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "firefox.exe",url)

Answer (score 0):

Wait this is a trick question....

If you are using a webframe framework just chuck in some javascript or jquery to do it eg.

window.open(url);